# c# xml serialization add namespace to nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I have two class : Osoba, test

```
public class test
{

    public string raz { get; set; }
    public string dwa { get; set; }
}

public class Osoba
{
    public test tehe { get; set; }
}
```

I also add namespaces to main root and seralize

```
        Osoba ne = new Osoba();
        test t1 = new praca2.test();


        t1.dwa = "fgfg";
        t1.raz = "dfdfdfdf";
        ne.tehe = t1;            
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("dfs", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution");
        ns.Add("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/dataFields");
        ns.Add("pc", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls");

        XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Osoba));
        var xml = @"D:\dupa1.xml";

        using (var stream = new FileStream(xml, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
            {
                xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, ne,ns);
                xml = stream.ToString(); // Your XML
            }
        }
```

I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Osoba xmlns:dfs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution"xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls"xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/dataFields">
 <tehe>
    <raz>dfdfdfdf</raz>
    <dwa>fgfg</dwa>
 </tehe>
</Osoba>
```

I want add to node namespaces examle:

```
...
  <pc:tehe>
     <dfs:raz>dfdfdfdf</dfs:raz>
     <dfs:dwa>fgfg</dfs:dwa>
  </pc:tehe>
```

How I can do it?
I try add class atribute which set namespace

```
   [XmlRoot("Node", Namespace="http://flibble")]
```

but it bad idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there you just need to modify your classes slightly:

```
    public class test
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution")]
        public string raz { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution")]
        public string dwa { get; set; }
    }

    public class Osoba
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls")]
        public test tehe { get; set; }
    }
```

Sample implementation copied mostly from yours:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Osoba ne = new Osoba();
            test t1 = new test();

            t1.dwa = "fgfg";
            t1.raz = "dfdfdfdf";
            ne.tehe = t1;

            XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Osoba));

            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("dfs", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution");
            ns.Add("pc", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls");
            var xml = @"D:\dupa1.xml";


            using (var stream = new FileStream(xml, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, ne, ns);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

You will get this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Osoba xmlns:dfs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution" xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls">
    <pc:tehe>
        <dfs:raz>dfdfdfdf</dfs:raz>
        <dfs:dwa>fgfg</dfs:dwa>
    </pc:tehe>
</Osoba>
```

Hth...

Answer (score 0):

Uisng xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication42
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xmlHeader =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                "<Osoba xmlns:dfs=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution\"" +
                    " xmlns:pc=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls\"" + 
                    " xmlns:d=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/dataFields\">" +
                "</Osoba>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlHeader);

            XElement osoba = doc.Root;
            XNamespace dfsNs = osoba.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("dfs");
            XNamespace pcNs = osoba.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("pc");

            osoba.Add(new XElement(pcNs + "tehe", new object[] {
                new XElement(dfsNs + "raz", "dfdfdfdf"),
                new XElement(dfsNs + "dwa", "fgfg")
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are new at C#.I suggest you to study C# basics, design patterns and repository pattern.For your requirement you can use below codes

```
public class Tehe
{
    public string Raz { get; set; }
    public string Dwa { get; set; }
}

public class TeheRepository
{
    private System.Xml.Linq.XDocument xmlDatas;

    public TeheRepository(string filePath)
    {
        xmlDatas = XDocument.Load(filePath);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Tehe> FindAll()
    {
        return xmlDatas.Elements().Elements().Select(tehe => 
        {
            Tehe t = new Tehe();
            t.Dwa = tehe.Elements().ElementAt(1).Value;
            t.Raz = tehe.Elements().ElementAt(0).Value;
            return t;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How does all this code help the OP with `namespaces` and `prefixes`?

Comment: Do not you want to make Tehe objects from you xml file